# How to use next-auth middleware

Tags: next.js, middleware, next-auth

I'm having a problem with next-auth(^4.22.1), next(13.4.7)
The code
in the middlerware.js  is

```
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";

export const config = { matcher: ["/test"] };
```

after login whenever go to that test route the page is still loading and in the terminal's console showing this
Error: socket hang up
at connResetException (node:internal/errors:692:14)
at Socket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:478:23)
at Socket.emit (node:events:539:35)
at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1345:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
code: 'ECONNRESET'
}

after login whenever go to the protected route called test should be render as ususal

Comment: It seems to be an issue with the page itself, not the middleware. Please show page code for the test route.

Comment: const Test = () => {
 return (
  
   <div>Test</div>
  
 );
};

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me. I guess we need more information around the auth configuration and eventual changes to the api route.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here's link for my project please take a look
[github-link](https://github.com/painghtetaung/next-auth-middleware)
@grekier